# Converting a whole word of morse code into letter

Tags: javascript, morse-code

I am creating a morse code translator. I got stuck at translating a whole word of morse into word of letters. It works for me if I only type a single letter in morse, but once I type more than 1 letter it brakes, any idea how I can fix that?

```
const displayInMorse = () => {
  const inputValue = document
    .getElementById("message")
    .value.toLowerCase()
    .split("");
  console.log(inputValue);
  inputValue.forEach((letter) => {
    const indexOfLetter = alphabetLetters.indexOf(letter);
    console.log(morseLetters[indexOfLetter]);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += morseLetters[indexOfLetter];
  });
};

const displayInLetters = () => {
  const inputValue = document
    .getElementById("message")
    .value
    .split(" ");
  console.log(inputValue);
  inputValue.forEach((letter) => {
    const indexOfLetter = morseLetters.indexOf(letter);
    console.log(alphabetLetters[indexOfLetter]);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += alphabetLetters[indexOfLetter];
  });
} 

const displayTranslated = () => {   
  const inputValue = document
  .getElementById("message").value
  const testMorse = (/^[^-.]+$/)
  const testLetters = (/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)
  testMorse.test(inputValue) ? displayInMorse() 
  : testLetters.test(inputValue) ? displayInLetters() 
  : alert("Use only latin letters or morse letters")
}
```

I have 2 arrays of strings, one of them is in Morse the other one is in Letters.

Now for example, if I input `___.___.` that gives me the letter "c"
If I input it 3 times, without space in between it gives me "undefined".

In my displayInLetters function, if I change the `.split(" ")` to `.split("")`, the `___.___.` gives me "tttettte", which is understandable, as it splits it down to a single symbol. I know I am missing 1 step somewhere, but cannot get my head around it. Do I need to `.split(" ")` then `.split("")` and then `.join("")`?

I was reading in the forum, but couldn't find anything that would be helpful in my case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Take care, everyone!

Comment: the problem is that a single letter in morse code has more than one character. So to parse morse code to letters you SHOULD NOT split into single characters but parse chunks of charactersc at once that correspond to a single letter. This is your problem

Comment: I think it's not possible without a letter-separator because morse codes do not have a defined length. For example ```- . . .``` can be either interpreted as ```B``` (one letter) or as ```TEEE``` (```-``` for ```T``` and 3x ```E``` for ```.```) Also ```TS``` would be a possible interpretation.

Comment: the morse code has three symbols, short, long and pause, all of them are required to unambiguously determine which letter is encoded. Without pause one could try to guess the meaning by context.

Comment: @flappix I thought about that, but not sure how I could do it in the JS, I thought about asking the users to separate letters with either a space or "/" but that would be very bad UX. Any advice of how to achieve that in JS?

Comment: It's not bad UX in my opinion, that's just the way morse code is working. People at the telegraph offices did the same thing.

Comment: @flappix okay then, if a more experienced dev says it's not a bad UX i'll do it. I couldn't really understand of how to do it otherway. In my current functions it works with a "space" separator between the letters. So basically I've had it, but haven't instructed users of how to use it. Thank you for the quick respond dude, appreciate it!